# Problema al lanzar entrenamiento con el api de TF

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, inteligencia-artificial

quiero entrenar mi propio modelo de reconocimiento de objetos para lo cual estoy intentando usar el script `model_main.py` que se encuntra en la carpeta del api `/models/research/object_detection` pero al ejecutarlo de la siguiente manera:

`python3 model_main.py --logtostderr --model_dir=/home/alexander/Documentos/proyecto/Training/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29/ --pipeline_config_path=/home/alexander/Documentos/proyecto/Training/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config`

me genera lo siguiente y no empieza el entrenamiento:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Forced number of epochs for all eval validations to be 1.
W0111 23:57:18.099197 139762259621696 model_lib.py:793] Forced number of epochs for all eval validations to be 1.
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting train_steps: None
I0111 23:57:18.099363 139762259621696 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting train_steps: None
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting use_bfloat16: False
I0111 23:57:18.099413 139762259621696 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting use_bfloat16: False
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting sample_1_of_n_eval_examples: 1
I0111 23:57:18.099469 139762259621696 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting sample_1_of_n_eval_examples: 1
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting eval_num_epochs: 1
I0111 23:57:18.099525 139762259621696 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting eval_num_epochs: 1
WARNING:tensorflow:Expected number of evaluation epochs is 1, but instead encountered `eval_on_train_input_config.num_epochs` = 0. Overwriting `num_epochs` to 1.
W0111 23:57:18.099602 139762259621696 model_lib.py:809] Expected number of evaluation epochs is 1, but instead encountered `eval_on_train_input_config.num_epochs` = 0. Overwriting `num_epochs` to 1.
INFO:tensorflow:create_estimator_and_inputs: use_tpu False, export_to_tpu None
I0111 23:57:18.099665 139762259621696 model_lib.py:846] create_estimator_and_inputs: use_tpu False, export_to_tpu None
INFO:tensorflow:Using config: {'_model_dir': '/home/alexander/Documentos/proyecto/Training/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29/', '_tf_random_seed': None, '_save_summary_steps': 100, '_save_checkpoints_steps': None, '_save_checkpoints_secs': 600, '_session_config': allow_soft_placement: true
graph_options {
  rewrite_options {
    meta_optimizer_iterations: ONE
  }
}
, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_log_step_count_steps': 100, '_train_distribute': None, '_device_fn': None, '_protocol': None, '_eval_distribute': None, '_experimental_distribute': None, '_experimental_max_worker_delay_secs': None, '_service': None, '_cluster_spec': <tensorflow.python.training.server_lib.ClusterSpec object at 0x7f1cb2d19310>, '_task_type': 'worker', '_task_id': 0, '_global_id_in_cluster': 0, '_master': '', '_evaluation_master': '', '_is_chief': True, '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_num_worker_replicas': 1}
I0111 23:57:18.100012 139762259621696 estimator.py:209] Using config: {'_model_dir': '/home/alexander/Documentos/proyecto/Training/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29/', '_tf_random_seed': None, '_save_summary_steps': 100, '_save_checkpoints_steps': None, '_save_checkpoints_secs': 600, '_session_config': allow_soft_placement: true
graph_options {
  rewrite_options {
    meta_optimizer_iterations: ONE
  }
}
, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_log_step_count_steps': 100, '_train_distribute': None, '_device_fn': None, '_protocol': None, '_eval_distribute': None, '_experimental_distribute': None, '_experimental_max_worker_delay_secs': None, '_service': None, '_cluster_spec': <tensorflow.python.training.server_lib.ClusterSpec object at 0x7f1cb2d19310>, '_task_type': 'worker', '_task_id': 0, '_global_id_in_cluster': 0, '_master': '', '_evaluation_master': '', '_is_chief': True, '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_num_worker_replicas': 1}
WARNING:tensorflow:Estimator's model_fn (<function create_model_fn.<locals>.model_fn at 0x7f1cb2d09440>) includes params argument, but params are not passed to Estimator.
W0111 23:57:18.100254 139762259621696 model_fn.py:630] Estimator's model_fn (<function create_model_fn.<locals>.model_fn at 0x7f1cb2d09440>) includes params argument, but params are not passed to Estimator.
INFO:tensorflow:Not using Distribute Coordinator.
I0111 23:57:18.100585 139762259621696 estimator_training.py:186] Not using Distribute Coordinator.
INFO:tensorflow:Running training and evaluation locally (non-distributed).
I0111 23:57:18.100709 139762259621696 training.py:612] Running training and evaluation locally (non-distributed).
INFO:tensorflow:Start train and evaluate loop. The evaluate will happen after every checkpoint. Checkpoint frequency is determined based on RunConfig arguments: save_checkpoints_steps None or save_checkpoints_secs 600.
I0111 23:57:18.100878 139762259621696 training.py:700] Start train and evaluate loop. The evaluate will happen after every checkpoint. Checkpoint frequency is determined based on RunConfig arguments: save_checkpoints_steps None or save_checkpoints_secs 600.
INFO:tensorflow:Skipping training since max_steps has already saved.
I0111 23:57:18.103509 139762259621696 estimator.py:360] Skipping training since max_steps has already saved.
```

Tambien intente ejecutarlo con el scrip `train.py` que se encuentra en el directorio `/models/research/object_detection/legacy`, lo ejecute de la siguiente manera `python3 train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=/home/alexander/Documentos/proyecto/Training/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29/ --pipeline_config_path=/home/alexander/Documentos/proyecto/Training/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config` no obstante de esta forma me aparece lo siguiente:

```
File "/home/alexander/anaconda3/envs/TF/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 324, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "train.py", line 182, in main
    graph_hook_fn=graph_rewriter_fn)
  File "/home/alexander/Documentos/proyecto/tf/models/research/object_detection/legacy/trainer.py", line 376, in train
    keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours=keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours)
  File "/home/alexander/anaconda3/envs/TF/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 825, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "/home/alexander/anaconda3/envs/TF/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 837, in build
    self._build(self._filename, build_save=True, build_restore=True)
  File "/home/alexander/anaconda3/envs/TF/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 875, in _build
    build_restore=build_restore)
  File "/home/alexander/anaconda3/envs/TF/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 508, in _build_internal
    restore_sequentially, reshape)
  File "/home/alexander/anaconda3/envs/TF/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 328, in _AddRestoreOps
    restore_sequentially)
  File "/home/alexander/anaconda3/envs/TF/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 575, in bulk_restore
    return io_ops.restore_v2(filename_tensor, names, slices, dtypes)
  File "/home/alexander/anaconda3/envs/TF/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 1696, in restore_v2
    name=name)
  File "/home/alexander/anaconda3/envs/TF/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 788, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/alexander/anaconda3/envs/TF/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alexander/anaconda3/envs/TF/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3616, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/alexander/anaconda3/envs/TF/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2005, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

ERROR:tensorflow:==================================
Object was never used (type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>):
<tf.Tensor 'init_ops/report_uninitialized_variables/boolean_mask/GatherV2:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>
If you want to mark it as used call its "mark_used()" method.
It was originally created here:
  File "train.py", line 186, in <module>
    tf.app.run()  File "/home/alexander/anaconda3/envs/TF/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)  File "/home/alexander/anaconda3/envs/TF/lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 325, in run
    raise  File "/home/alexander/anaconda3/envs/TF/lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))  File "/home/alexander/anaconda3/envs/TF/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 324, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)  File "train.py", line 182, in main
    graph_hook_fn=graph_rewriter_fn)  File "/home/alexander/Documentos/proyecto/tf/models/research/object_detection/legacy/trainer.py", line 415, in train
    saver=saver)  File "/home/alexander/anaconda3/envs/TF/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tf_slim/learning.py", line 788, in train
    should_retry = True  File "/home/alexander/anaconda3/envs/TF/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/tf_should_use.py", line 193, in wrapped
    return _add_should_use_warning(fn(*args, **kwargs))
==================================
E0111 23:47:56.769966 139791945934656 tf_should_use.py:71] ==================================
Object was never used (type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>):
<tf.Tensor 'init_ops/report_uninitialized_variables/boolean_mask/GatherV2:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>
If you want to mark it as used call its "mark_used()" method.
It was originally created here:
  File "train.py", line 186, in <module>
    tf.app.run()  File "/home/alexander/anaconda3/envs/TF/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)  File "/home/alexander/anaconda3/envs/TF/lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 325, in run
    raise  File "/home/alexander/anaconda3/envs/TF/lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))  File "/home/alexander/anaconda3/envs/TF/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 324, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)  File "train.py", line 182, in main
    graph_hook_fn=graph_rewriter_fn)  File "/home/alexander/Documentos/proyecto/tf/models/research/object_detection/legacy/trainer.py", line 415, in train
    saver=saver)  File "/home/alexander/anaconda3/envs/TF/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tf_slim/learning.py", line 788, in train
    should_retry = True  File "/home/alexander/anaconda3/envs/TF/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/tf_should_use.py", line 193, in wrapped
    return _add_should_use_warning(fn(*args, **kwargs))
==================================
```

La version de TF que estoy usando es la 1.14.0, si alguien sabe que puede estar pasando le agradeceria si me puede ayudar, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Vale, voy por partes.

### Primera traza

Lo primero no es una traza de error, **es información sobre el procesado** que te lanza el modelo sobre distintas cosas, configuración de hiperparámetros, que no estás utilizando el entrenamiento distribuido, etc.

También tienes algún [warnings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html) (que no errores) que el mismo resuelve y te dice como lo ha resuelto. Por ejemplo en el archivo de configuración encuentra que el número de epocas es 0 y lo cambia a uno.

Por último todo finaliza diciendo:

> Skipping training since max_steps has already saved.

Basicamente te dice que tu le has puesto al modelo un número de pasos, y que para ese número de pasos ya lo tienes guardado. Es decir ya has entrenado un modelo previamente, por lo que no tiene sentido volver a entrenarlo.

Tienes dos opciones para solucionar esto:

1. Borrar el modelo que ya has entrenado para empezar de cero. Para ello ves donde has definido el directorio de tu modelo, `model_dir` y borra lo que hay dentro de la carpeta `checkpoint`. **Ojo, que estás borrando el modelo entrenado**
2. Definir un directorio distinto `model_dir` en el que se hará el entrenamiento.

### Segunda traza.

Aunque no pone nada de que indique que es un `Error` por experiencia parece que si lo es (por favor si has cortado parte de la traza agregalá al completo).

Por lo que sea `Tensorflow` parece que no es capaz de iniciar el grafo de computación y por tanto no puede llevar a cabo el entrenamiento.

Puede ser por diversos problemas:

- Un bug en la versión de Tensorflow, estás en el versión 1.14 y la actual es la 2.4, esta versión [tiene cerca de dos años](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#history)
- Problema con librerías o dependencias
- El mismo problema que en la traza anterior, que ya lo tienes entrenado.

Comment: Hola Alberto gracias por comentar, actualice la segunda traza con un poco mas de contenido, gracias